# Mathematica - How to execute a function inside a while loop?

Tags: function, loops, while-loop, wolfram-mathematica

I'm new to Mathematica, and am trying to get a function to execute in a while loop. I think the best way to explain this is by using an example.
So, say you have a normal, simply while loop like the following:

```
In[1]:= x = 5;
While[x > 0, Print[x]; x--];
```

This outputs the following:
5
4
3
2
1 as one would expect.
However, why doesn't this work:

```
x=5;

While[x > 0, g[]; x--];
g[] = Print[x];
```

When I try something like the above, it just outputs 5 and then stops. I'm used to Python and something like that would work in Python - how can I make it work in Mathematica. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first time you run this

```
x=5;
While[x > 0, g[]; x--];
g[]:= Print[x];
```

it prints nothing because the function g has not been defined before it is used.

The second time you run it it prints your desired 5,4,3,2,1 because it has previously seen the definition of g.

You can make this work every time if you define g before first use, like this

```
g[]:= Print[x];
x=5;
While[x > 0, g[]; x--];
```